# Where to host a data ingestion ETL ? input data (csv file) automatically from Azure blob storage to Azure Posgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, azure, csv

I would like to do a daily ingesting job that takes a CSV file from blob storage and put it integrate it into a PostgreSQL database. I have the constraint to use python. Which solution do you recommend me to use for building/hosting my ETL solution ?

Have a nice day :)
**Additional information:**
The size and shape of the CSV file are 1.35 GB, (1292532, 54).
I will push to the database only 12 columns out of 54.

Comment: You can use the Azure function with blob trigger to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python , once .csv file has been uploaded, your function load it from blob storage and push data to Azure Posgresql

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Azure Data Factory to achieve this. New a Copy Data activity, source is your csv and sink is PostgreSQL database. In the Mapping setting, just select the columns you need. Finally, create a schedule trigger to run it.